# Presenting UIPopoverController without dismissing the keyboard

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, first-responder, inputaccessoryview

I'm attempting to present a UIPopoverController as the result of a UIButton tap. The UIButton is contained within a custom view that's being displayed as a UITextField's inputAccessoryView. The issue I'm seeing is that when the UIPopoverController is presented the UITextField displaying the inputAccessoryView loses first responder status and, as a result, dismisses the keyboard. Is there any way to avoid this? Ideally I'd like the keyboard and inputAccessoryView to remain visible while the UIPopoverController is presented.

I've attached a screenshot below demonstrating what I'm hoping to achieve (right), and what I'm currently seeing (left).

[image: An image demonstrating what I'm hoping to achieve (right), and what I'm currently seeing (left)]

Comment: You might need to catch events when the `UITextField` loses the first responder status. This has to do with `–(BOOL)canResignFirstResponder` (before it happens) and `-(BOOL)resignFirstResponder` (once it lost the status). But to handle these you'll need to create your own `UITextField` subclass, and I'm not even sure it will work. Another thing you might want to look at is the `UITextFieldDelegate`, which can notify you of these events on your text field: `-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` and `-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField`.

Comment: Not sure if this would work but have you tried implementing disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal and returning YES in the view controller?